# Kdevelop gdb error "You need gdb 7.0.0 or higher."

Tags: c, gdb, kdevelop

When trying to debug in kedevelop I'm getting the error:

> You need gdb 7.0.0 or higher. You are using: Registered pretty
> printers for UE classes

but I have a higher version than that:

> $ gdb --version GNU gdb (Debian 10.1-1.7) 10.1.90.20210103-git
> Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU
> GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free
> software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO
> WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

I do have UE built but I'm not actually using it. The project is just the simple hello world simple cmake C template. I don't know what's going on or why it's putting this up.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found an answer in an odd chinese blog using google translate. [Link to Blog](https://blog.csdn.net/LeGe675797663/article/details/88408366). In summary it seems like the act of building Unreal Engine source creates a gdb config file in home called .gdbinit. And this is where the problem lies.

Simply moving the config file and restarting kdevelop solves the problem:

```
$ mv .gdbinit .gdbinit_ue
```

This way you can reinstate it if you ever need to play around with UE again.

Comment: Where is this file ```.gdbinit``` located?