# KDevelop not detecting GDB for C++ projects in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, gdb, ubuntu-20.04, kdevelop

I am getting the following error while attempting to debug a C++ project in KDevelop:

```
You need gdb 7.0.0 or higher.
You are using: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 10.2-0ubuntu1~20.04~1) 10.2
```

The solution, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295158/kdevelop-gdb-error-you-need-gdb-7-0-0-or-higher), appears to be about renaming a file. However, I can't find the same. I don't think it is getting created. Please see if there are any other solutions?

Comment: The other post said it is located *in home*. Did you check with `cd; ls -a .*` ?

Comment: Yes, it was not there.